# How can I add a Static Block between Discount and CrossSell

Tags: magento2, cart, cross-sells

i want to add a block between Apply Discount form and crossell Block on Cart page in magento 2

[image]

I have tried this Code but its not working

```
 <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.items">
     <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Block.php" cacheable="false"
     name="my.static.block" before="checkout.cart.crosssell" template="Vendor_Module::file.phtml"  />
 </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.items">
     <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Block.php" cacheable="false"
     name="my.static.block" after="checkout.cart.container" template="Vendor_Module::file.phtml"  />
 </referenceContainer>

Comment: Try this working or not

Comment: i have tried this its not working :(

Comment: working for me. can u please check your xml file called or not. <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.items" remove="true"/> put this line and check content removed or not

Comment: all content is removed..

Comment: Check my answer, Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have added the CMS Block between Coupon field and cross-sell products. add below code to your **checkout_cart_index.xml** file.

```
<referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.container">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block.on.cart" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_on_cart</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

So your code look like below.

```
<referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.container">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Block" cacheable="false" name="my.static.block" template="Vendor_Module::file.phtml" after="-" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Check the below screenshot.

[image]

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: i am doing the same but i am doing using `layout_load_before` event not by xml... maybe this is reason its not working